# Filtering array based on nested property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which has a nested parameter in it and I want to return only those array elements that pass filter based on that nested parameter which is in turn also an array of objects.

```
[{q:1,w:2,props:{p:1, messages:[{status:true},{status:false},{status:true}]},
{q:3,w:5,props:{p:2, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:false}]},
{q:7,w:0,props:{p:3, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:true}]}
]
```

My aim is to filter only those objects that contain at least one message with status true.
In this example I would expect to get an array of two objects

```
[{q:1,w:2,props:{p:1, messages:[{status:true},{status:false},{status:true}]},
{q:7,w:0,props:{p:3, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:true}]}
]
```

Thanks for help and advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will let you check if a condition is true at least once. You can use that to filter: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr = [{q:1,w:2,props:{p:1, messages:[{status:true},{status:false},{status:true}]}},{q:3,w:5,props:{p:2, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:false}]}},{q:7,w:0,props:{p:3, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:true}]}}]

let filtered = arr.filter(item => item.props.messages.some(m => m.status === true))
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter.

```
var result= items.filter(item =>{
    return item.props.messages.some(obj => obj.status === true)
})
```

I created this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/81ue32ra/2/

```js
var items = [{q:1,w:2,props:{p:1, messages:[{status:true},{status:false},{status:true}]}},
{q:3,w:5,props:{p:2, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:false}]}},
{q:7,w:0,props:{p:3, messages:[{status:false},{status:false},{status:true}]}}
];

var result = items.filter(item =>{
   return item.props.messages.some(obj => obj.status === true)
});
    
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I added your fiddle as a snippet, please run and edit given the syntax issue.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks, I had already fixed that in the fiddle, not sure why it didn't save.

Answer (score 0):

Just `filter` the main array and check if `some` of the messages status property is true.

Answer (score 0):

let data = your array;

```
data.filter(obj => obj.props.messages.some(message => message.status).length > 0)
```