# Filter array of objects based on value of an inside array

Tags: typescript

I want to select from array `courses` only the courses that have at least one field with id in `fieldIds` array. bellow is the format of  thw arrays:

```
courses = [
    {id: 5, name:"some name1", fields:[{id: 28, name:"field name"}, {id: 29, name:"field name2"}]},
    {id: 18, name:"some name2", fields:[{id: 11, name:"field name"}, {id: 28, name:"field name2"}]},
    {id: 7, name:"some name3", fields:[{id: 29, name:"field name"}, {id: 9, name:"field name2"}]}
]

fieldIds = [29, 9]
```

So the result should be:

```
courses = [
    {id: 5, name:"some name1", fields:[{id: 28, name:"field name"}, {id: 29, name:"field name2"}]},
    {id: 7, name:"some name3", fields:[{id: 29, name:"field name"}, {id: 9, name:"field name2"}]}
]
```

This is what I tried and I always got the same array it changes nothing

```
fieldIds.map(fieldId => {
    courses = courses.filter(course => course.fields.map(f => f.id == fieldId);
});
```

**EDIT** after trying the response of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565185/filtering-array-based-on-nested-property) as follow:

```
fieldIds.map(fieldId => {
    courses = courses.filter(course => course.fields.some(f => f.id == fielded))
}
```

if the fieldIds contain a couple of IDs for example the function returns courses belong to all fields. (and I want to extract the courses that have at least one of the selected fields)

Comment: Try to explain what your script does and you might get an idea why it doesn't work as expected. Why `fieldIds.map(...)` Why `course.fields.map(...)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering array based on nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565185/filtering-array-based-on-nested-property)

Comment: No, it does not, see my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```js
const courses = [
    {id: 5, name:"some name1", fields:[{id: 28, name:"field name"}, {id: 29, name:"field name2"}]},
    {id: 18, name:"some name2", fields:[{id: 11, name:"field name"}, {id: 28, name:"field name2"}]},
    {id: 7, name:"some name3", fields:[{id: 29, name:"field name"}, {id: 9, name:"field name2"}]}
];

const fieldIds = [29, 9];

const filtered_courses = courses.filter(course => course.fields.some(field => fieldIds.includes(field.id)));

console.log(filtered_courses);
```

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the *courses* array with the condition (*[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)*) verifying that **at least one** element in the *fields* array has an equal value from *fieldIds* array.

PS: If *fields* array(s) and *fieldIds* array are sorted in ASC or DESC order the "algorithm" is much faster since the *some* method return earlier.